# Dynamic multi-dimensional array

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have to create a three-dimensional array using class A as element ,class A is defined like below, should I use `vector<vector<vector<A> > >` or `boost::multi_array`? Which one is better?

```
struct C
{
    int C_1;
    short C_2;
};

class B
{
public:
    bool B_1;
    vector<C> C_;
};

class A
{
public:
    bool A_1;
    B B_[6];
};
```

Comment: `vector<C> C)=_;` What is that?

Comment: If you use boost the size of your project will swell. Is file size important?

Comment: @Borgleader it should be vector<C> C_; :P

Comment: @Dreamz you need to fix your own code instead of post a comment for the typo.

Comment: @jeSuisBeau Yes, there will be millions elements in this dynamic array, so I have to control the size.

Comment: @billz Sorry I have forgotten that I can edit my post :P

Comment: Elements in the array is different than file size. The elements will be stored in RAM, more than likely.

Comment: @jeSuisBeau Each member variable value will be written into the file, so both RAM usage and file size need control~

Comment: Oh. I meant if you include some of the boost libraries your exe size will increase. Sorry for the misunderstanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know the size of all three dimensions at the time, that you write your code, and if you don't need checking for array bounds, then just use traditional arrays:

```
const int N1 = ...
const int N2 = ...
const int N3 = ...
A a[N1][N2][N3]
```

If the array dimensions can onlybe  determined at run time, but remain constant after program initialization, and if array usage is distributed uniformly, then boost::multi_array is your friend. However, if a lot of dynamic extension is going on at runtime, and/or if array sizes are not uniform (for example, you need A[0][0][0...99] but only A[2][3][0...3]), then the nested vector is likely the best solution. In the case of non-uniform sizes, put the dimension, whose size variies the most, as last dimension. Also, in the nested vector solution, it is generally a good idea to put small dimensions first.

Comment: Thanks very much, the array dimensions can onlybe determined at run time and there will also be many dynamic extension at runtime, however the array sizes are uniform for calculation, I will use nested vector as you suggested :)

Answer (score 0):

The main concern that I would have about using `vector<vector<vector<A> > >` would be making sure that the second- and third-level vectors all have the same length like they would in a traditional 3D array, since there would be nothing in the data type to enforce that. I'm not terribly familiar with `boost::multi_array`, but it looks like this isn't an issue there - you can `resize()` the whole array, but unless I'm mistaken you can't accidentally remove an item from the third row and leave it a different size than all of the other rows (for example).

So assuming concerns like file size and compile time aren't much of an issue, I would think you'd want `boost::multi_array`. If those things are an issue, you might want to consider using a plain-old 3D array, since that should beat either of the other two options hands-down in those areas.

Comment: You mean I should create a 3D array using pointer like int ***p if concerning about file size and compile time?

Comment: Only if file size and compile time are really a concern, as in something that you have to worry about regularly. I don't expect that they would be unless your target is some kind of embedded system; if your program will run on a typical computer, I doubt that it will make enough of a difference to notice, and you'd be better off using one of the other options that takes care of memory management and other issues for you.